# Excel Interop Save() doesn't work for setting password on an Excel file

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, excel-interop, office-automation

I am trying to set password on an Excel file using Excel Interop (.NET Framework 4.8.1 Console App).

It works, but only if I use `SaveAs()` and giving the same filename to replace the existing one.

If I use `Save()`, the file won't be set with a password.

This is the one that works:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace excel
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExcelUtil excelUtil = new ExcelUtil();
            excelUtil.passwordProtectExcel();
        }
    }
}


class ExcelUtil
{
    public string Filename = "C:\\websites\\excel_encrypt\\files\\file_to_encrypt.xlsx";
    private Excel.Application excelApp;
    private Excel.Workbook wb;

    public void passwordProtectExcel()
    {
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename);
        excelApp.Visible = true;
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false; // to prevent Excel from asking if I want to override existing file  or save changes
        string password = "some_password";
        wb.WritePassword = password;
        wb.SaveAs(Filename);
        wb.Close();
        wb = null;
        excelApp.Quit();
        excelApp = null;
    }
}
```

And the following does nothing:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace excel
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExcelUtil excelUtil = new ExcelUtil();
            excelUtil.passwordProtectExcel();
        }
    }
}


class ExcelUtil
{
    public string Filename = "C:\\websites\\excel_encrypt\\files\\file_to_encrypt.xlsx";
    private Excel.Application excelApp;
    private Excel.Workbook wb;

    public void passwordProtectExcel()
    {
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename);
        excelApp.Visible = true;
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false; // to prevent Excel from asking if I want to override existing file  or save changes
        string password = "some_password";
        wb.WritePassword = password;
        wb.Save();
        wb.Close();
        wb = null;
        excelApp.Quit();
        excelApp = null;
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: Where is the `passwordProtectExcel` method?

Comment: Do you get the same results when you do such steps manually?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev wow, I didn't even notice, I accidentally copied without the braces, this is the `passwordProtectExcel` method. thanks for letting me know. updated the post

Comment: Do you get the same results when you do such steps manually?

Comment: You mean if I use Excel to set password and then just click `Save` instead of `Save As` from within Excel GUI?

Comment: Yep. You are on the right avenue. Make sure that you deal with `WritePassword`, not `Password`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check whether setting a writing password is allowed:

```
 ' Set password to a string if allowed. 
 If ActiveWorkbook.WriteReserved = False Then 
   ActiveWorkbook.WritePassword = strPassword 
 End If
```

Also pay attention to the [Workbook.Password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.Password) property which returns or sets the password that must be supplied to open the specified workbook. While the [Workbook.WritePassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.writepassword) property returns or sets a string for the write password of a workbook.